# Iterator for structure "node" is not allowing data retrieval

Tags: c++

I'm struggling with an issue. I have our regular node structure and a list that stores node pointers. When I'm trying to retrieve values fro such list using an iterator, I'm not able to do so...

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    node* next;
};

int main()
{
    node * n = new node;
    n->data = 3;
    n->next = NULL;

    list<node*> l;
    l.push_front(n);
    list<node*>::iterator myIt = l.begin();

    cout << *myIt->data << endl;   // <-- the compiler shows an error here "Member reference base type "node*" is not a structure or union"
}
```

Perhaps I'm confused with the usage of iterators. Could you please suggest me a workaround?

Cheers!!!

Comment: You'll need to learn your operator precedences. Also, why is this tagged `c`?

Comment: List of pointers is double indirection, completely unnecessary in most cases. If it happens to be necessary in yours (i.e. polymorphism enabler), use smart pointers.

Answer (score 4):

Problem with operators precedence: use `cout << (*myIt)->data << endl;`

Answer (score 0):

```
  cout << *myIt->data << endl;
```

You need additionnal ()

```
  cout << (*myIt)->data << endl;
```

Bye,

Francis

Answer (score -1):

You are actually a bit confused, you need to do the following

```
cout << (*myIt)->data << endl;
```

You first have you dereference the pointer, then you can fetch the data.